# BDD in Cucumber

Tags: cucumber, bdd

While working on Ruby language i was facing the problem during cucumber execution.I wrote a basic program of Login Functionality with feature extension inside the feature folder after initializing cucumber in cmd,

Here is the code,

```
Feature: Verifying Login Functionality
 Scenario: Login with valid credentials
  Given user is on the login page
  When user enters username
  And user enters password
  And user clicks on signin button
  Then user is loggedin successfully
```

Moreover,I have defined steps in Step Definition folder with .rb extension.

Code:-

```
Given(/^user is on the login page$/) do
  puts "user is on login page"
end

When(/^user enters username$/) do
  puts "username"
end

When(/^user enters password$/) do
    puts "password"
end

When(/^user clicks on signin button$/) do
  puts "click on signin button"
end

Then(/^user is loggedin successfully$/) do
  puts "loggedin successfully"
end
```

[This is the screenshot after executing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHjcK.png)

Output cmd has to be like 1 scenario and 5 steps etc.

I saw that type of files that are edited in Step Definition and feature are not showing .rb and .feature but txt even though saved format is former ones.FYI!!

Please help!! btw i have just started learning ruby language so i want to ask will cucumber cover some rails portion as well.

Working on IDE "Eclipse" Software Tool "Cucumber".

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I would suggest you to rethink the scenario since it is possible to login in different ways then entering a username/password combination. Writing great scenarios is about behavior, not about implementation. Therefore this scenario could be like (first sentence could even be left out):
Given Paul is not logged in
When Paul tries to log in into the system
Then he should be successfully logged in

Comment: bro thanks!! on the track again..thanks a ton..